# Apache attack on compromised server, iframe injected by string replace

Tags: apache, security, iframe, code-injection

My server has been compromised recently. This morning, I have discovered that the intruder is injecting an iframe into each of my HTML pages. After testing, I have found out that the way he does that is by getting Apache (?) to replace every instance of

```
<body>
```

by

```
<iframe link to malware></iframe></body>
```

For example if I browse a file residing on the server consisting of:

```
</body>
</body>
```

Then my browser sees a file consisting of:

```
<iframe link to malware></iframe></body>
<iframe link to malware></iframe></body>
```

I have immediately stopped Apache to protect my visitors, but so far I have not been able to find what the intruder has changed on the server to perform the attack. I presume he has modified an Apache config file, but I have no idea which one. In particular, I have looked for recently modified files by time-stamp, but did not find anything noteworthy.

Thanks for any help.

Tuan.

PS: I am in the process of rebuilding a new server from scratch, but in the while, I would like to keep the old one running, since this is a business site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the details of your compromised server. While this is a fairly standard drive-by attack against Apache that you can, ideally, resolve by rolling back to a previous version of your web content and server configuration (if you have a colo, contact the technical team responsible for your backups), let's presume you're entirely on your own and need to fix the problem yourself.

Pulling from [StopBadware.org's documentation on the most common drive-by scenarios and resolution cases:](http://www.stopbadware.org/home/security)

> **Malicious scripts**
>
> Malicious scripts are often used to redirect site visitors to a
>   different website and/or load badware from another source. These
>   scripts will often be injected by an attacker into the content of your
>   web pages, or sometimes into other files on your server, such as
>   images and PDFs. Sometimes, instead of injecting the entire script
>   into your web pages, the attacker will only inject a pointer to a .js
>   or other file that the attacker saves in a directory on your web
>   server.
>
> Many malicious scripts use obfuscation to make them more difficult for
>   anti-virus scanners to detect:
>
> Some malicious scripts use names that look like they’re coming from
>   legitimate sites (note the misspelling of “analytics”):
>
> **.htaccess redirects**
>
> The Apache web server, which is used by many hosting providers, uses a
>   hidden server file called .htaccess to configure certain access
>   settings for directories on the website. Attackers will sometimes
>   modify an existing .htaccess file on your web server or upload new
>   .htaccess files to your web server containing instructions to redirect
>   users to other websites, often ones that lead to badware downloads or
>   fraudulent product sales.
>
> **Hidden iframes**
>
> An iframe is a section of a web page that loads content from another
>   page or site. Attackers will often inject malicious iframes into a web
>   page or other file on your server. Often, these iframes will be
>   configured so they don’t show up on the web page when someone visits
>   the page, but the malicious content they are loading will still load,
>   hidden from the visitor’s view.
>
> **How to look for it**
>
> If your site was reported as a badware site by Google, you can use
>   Google’s [Webmaster Tools](http://google.com/webmasters/tools) to get more information about what was
>   detected. This includes a sampling of pages on which the badware was
>   detected and, using a Labs feature, possibly even a sample of the bad
>   code that was found on your site. Certain information can also be
>   found on the Google Diagnostics page, which can be found by replacing
>   example.com in the following URL with your own site’s URL:
>   www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=example.com
>
> There exist several free and paid website scanning services on the
>   Internet that can help you zero in on specific badware on your site.
>   There are also tools that you can use on your web server and/or on a
>   downloaded copy of the files from your website to search for specific
>   text. StopBadware does not list or recommend such services, but the
>   volunteers in our [online community](http://badwarebusters.org/) will be glad to point you to their
>   favorites.

In short, use the stock-standard tools and scanners provided by Google first. If the threat can't otherwise be identified, you'll need to backpath through the code of your CMS, Apache configuration, SQL setup, and remaining content of your website to determine where you were compromised and what the right remediation steps should be.

Best of luck handling your issue!